# OpenGL - Draw a Triangle wherever I click?

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2015

I have an OpenGL project with a screen size of 1000x800, and I want to be able to draw a triangle when I click the left mouse button.

I already have a mouse function set up that works fine:

```
struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

std::vector <point> dots;
point OneDot;

void processMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{

    if ((button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) && (state == GLUT_DOWN))
    {
        int yy;
        yy = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        y = yy - y; /* In Glut, Y coordinate increases from top to bottom */
        OneDot.x = x;
        OneDot.y = y;

        dots.push_back(OneDot);
   }
}

void display(){
    for (int i = 0; i < dots.size();i++){
        glPointSize(10)
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2i(dots[i].x, dots[i].y);
    }
}
```

So in my `display()` function, how can I add some code that prints a triangle at the mouse location when I click?

### UPDATE:

Here's my current drawCircle function:

```
void drawCircle(float cx, float cy, float r, float num_segments) {

    // Sets variables for X, Y, Radius and Segments
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); // Red
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    // To set 0 as origin point
    for (int i = 0; i < num_segments; i++) {
        float theta = 2.0f * 3.14 * i / num_segments;

        float x = r * cosf(theta);
        float y = r * sinf(theta);

        glVertex2f(x + cx, y + cy);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Is there a way I could draw this function somehow at the mouse location when I left click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you're almost there. Two things you have to add: In your mouse event handler you have to set the flag that tells your window manager (in your case GLUT) to refresh the display. That function would be `glutPostRedisplay`.

Then in your display function you have to push 3 vertices instead of 1 and change the primitive type to GL_TRIANGLES. Like this

```
void processMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{

    if ((button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) && (state == GLUT_DOWN))
    {
        int yy;
        yy = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        y = yy - y; /* In Glut, Y coordinate increases from top to bottom */
        OneDot.x = x;
        OneDot.y = y;

        dots.push_back(OneDot);
        glutPostRedisplay(); ///<<<<<<<<<<
   }
}
```

and

```
void display(){
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for (int i = 0; i < dots.size();i++){
        glPointSize(10)

        glVertex2i(dots[i].x-3, dots[i].y-5);
        glVertex2i(dots[i].x+3, dots[i].y-5);
        glVertex2i(dots[i].x, dots[i].y+5);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

or, if you want to define the corners of the triangle(s) by the clicks just

```
void display(){
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for (int i = 0; i < dots.size();i++){
        glPointSize(10);

        glVertex2i(dots[i].x, dots[i].y);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

You don't really have to check if `3 <= dots.size()` because OpenGL will simply draw nothing then.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This helps me to understand more about how the primitives are actually working. Quick question, if I wanted to do the exact same thing but only with lines (So the triangle is not filled in), would I just used GL_LINES?

Comment: @BenTanos: Exactly. However you should also know that `glBegin` / `glEnd` has been obsolete for nearly 20 years. It's been kept supported for compatibility / legacy reasons, but OpenGL-3 core profile finally removed it. You should look into *Vertex Arrays* and once you've familiarized with them learn how to use *Vertex Buffer Objects*.

Comment: Looking into Vertex Arrays right now! Also using a similar method that you've used in your answer, could I use it to draw a circle also? I've updated my question just to show you the current `drawCircle` function I have at the moment.

Comment: @BenTanos: Yes, that's the idea. However `3.14` is a little bit imprecise, just use `M_PI` (defined in `math.h`). Also GL_POLYGON is deprecated (along with GL_QUADS), and you should use a GL_TRIANGLE_FAN instead; start with a vertex at the circle's center and you're good.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't  got experience  in glbegin notation, but seems you miss glend

It should be something like this:

```
void display(){
    glPointSize(10)
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (int i = 0; i < dots.size();i++){            
        glVertex2i(dots[i].x, dots[i].y);
    }
    glEnd()
}
```

Comment: First of all, I want to be able to print a Triangle so this doesn't even answer my question. Secondly, putting a `glEnd()` will stop me from being able to print multiple shapes when clicking more than once...

Comment: @BenTanos: glBegin and glEnd must be balanced.

Comment: Then, first of all, you need use GL_TRIANGLES instead of GL_POINTS. Secondly you need use display function every frame and in a single frame fucntion use glBegin() ... draw something ... glEnd.

Comment: since the triangle has three vertices you also need chek and if dots.size() !=3 don't draw triangle